# Pigpio not closing

Tags: python, sensor, pigpio

I have a program that is meant to read data:

```
import pigpio

pi = pigpio.pi()

if not pi.connected:
    exit()

h = pi.i2c_open(1, 0x5a)





c, data = pi.i2c_read_device(h,0x09)



print(data)




pi.i2c_close(h)

pi.stop()
```

When I try and run it, I get data but it crashes when it tries to run `pi.stop()`.

The error message is:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 1106, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 977, in _pigpio_command
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate this behavior.  Which version of pigpio are you using (`pigs pigpv`) ?

Comment: the command returns the number 60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an `import time` at the top and a `time.sleep(0.1)` before the `pi.stop()`.  There may be a race condition, although I don't see why there should be.

```py
import time
import pigpio

pi = pigpio.pi()

if not pi.connected:
    exit()

h = pi.i2c_open(1, 0x5a)

c, data = pi.i2c_read_device(h, 0x09)

print(data)

pi.i2c_close(h)

time.sleep(0.1)

pi.stop()
```

Comment: I am getting data but I am struggling to interpret it as it has less bytes than it should : (9L, bytearray(b'\x01\xc7\x00\x00\x023\xc1\x00\x7f'))

Comment: also the problem I had earlier seems to be with I2c or smbus as the raw read device works but read block data gives the same impossible data that started this: (9L, bytearray(b'\xb5\x7f\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'))

Comment: The `\x023` is two bytes, it prints hex for non-ASCII characters, so that is hex 02 followed by the character 3 (hex 33).  It might be easier if you print data[0], data[1], etc.  The device does not seem to support SMBus commands, you will have to use i2c read device.

Comment: the bytearray is all one thing, how do I separate it? it is all in data[1]

Comment: I have fixed it and got reliable and accurate data from my program, many thanks for your kind assistance

Comment: I have been struggling with this for over half a year so thanks for helping me get this working